# Github returns “Problems parsing JSON” when trying to create issue which contains Chinese character

Tags: json, github

I'm attempting to create an issue on github using curl. 
If there is any Chinese character exist in the json, it always returns "Problems parsing JSON". 

`curl -i -H 'Authorization: token xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
   -d '{ \
        "title": "sfsd", \
        "body": "We should have one", \
        "labels": ["中文"] \
      }' \
   https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/issues`

Comment: I also get the same error when trying to request using php

Comment: It seems to be a bug. May be I should report it to github? But I don't know how